# Rename SonataUserBundle roles

Tags: php, symfony

I use SonataUserBundle extending FOSUserBundle, So I need to rename roles name because I have that in my group form :

```
ROLE_USER: ROLE_USER
ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN
ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN
```

But I want something like that:

```
Users
Administrators
Editors
```

My `security.yml`:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER: [ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    SONATA:
        - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT # if you are not using acl then this line must be uncommented
        - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_BLOCK_EDIT
```

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: Look at my first post.. I want to have : Administrators + Users + Editors checkbox in my form instead of ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIn, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN

Comment: Hello, did you find the solution? I need this also.